# Why did you call the camera and take pictures from the album and not return the image?

Tags: android, android-camera

As the title says.My Android device was 6.0, and when I called the camera and the photo album, it didn't return the image to the `ImageView` I specified.

**This is my MainActivity code:**

```
package com.example.raymond.myandroidproject.activity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.raymond.myandroidproject.R;
import com.example.raymond.myandroidproject.widget.PhotoDialog;
import com.liji.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext;
    private PhotoDialog dialog;
    private Uri imageUri;
    public static final int TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    public static final int CHOOSE_PHOTO = 2;
    private CircleImageView circleImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.hello);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = new PhotoDialog(mContext, R.style.PhotoDialog);
                dialog.show();
                Button btn_photoAlbum = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_photoAlbum);
                btn_photoAlbum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                            }, 1);
                        } else {
                            openAlbum();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
                Button btn_photoCamera = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_photoCamera);
                btn_photoCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
//                创建File 对象，用于存储拍照后的图片
                        File outputImage = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "out_image.jpg");
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            if (outputImage.exists()) {
                                outputImage.delete();
                            }
                            outputImage.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {

                            imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this
                                    , "com.example.raymond.myandroidproject.fileprovider", outputImage);
                        } else {
                            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(outputImage);
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }





    /**
     * open album
     */
    private void openAlbum() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_PHOTO);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permission, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    openAlbum();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "ni shengming le quanxian", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_PHOTO:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri));
                        circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_headIcon);
                        circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        if (bitmap== null){
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Bitmap is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case CHOOSE_PHOTO:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//                        判断手机系统版本
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                            handleImageOnKitKat(data);
                        } else {
                            handleImageBeforeKitKat(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void handleImageOnKitKat(Intent data) {
        String imagePath = null;
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(this, uri)) {
//            如果是document 类型的Uri,则通过document id 处理
            String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            if ("com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                String id = docId.split(":")[1];
                String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=" + id;
                imagePath = getImagePath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, selection);
            } else if ("com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_dwonloads")
                        , Long.valueOf(docId));
                imagePath = getImagePath(contentUri, null);
            } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
//                如果是content 类型的Uri,则使用普通方式处理
                imagePath = getImagePath(uri, null);
            } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                imagePath = uri.getPath();
            }
            displayImage(imagePath);
        }

    }

    private void displayImage(String imagePath) {
        if (imagePath != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            if (bitmap== null){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Bitmap is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "can' find the picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private String getImagePath(Uri uri, String selection) {
        String path = null;
//        通过Uri 和 selectio 来获取这是的图片路径
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return path;
    }

    private void handleImageBeforeKitKat(Intent data) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String imagePath = getImagePath(uri, null);
        displayImage(imagePath);
    }


}
```

**This is my Mainfest.xml :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.raymond.myandroidproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.SearchActivity"></activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.raymond.myandroidproject.fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
                />

        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my `file_paths.xml`  But t it reminds me that the path value cannot be empty, and that the path value is empty is not the directory under storage?

[image]

I hope I can get the help of a great engineer.

Comment: your if statement (requestCode == RESULT_OK) it should be (resultCode == RESULT_OK)

Comment: Thank you very much.It works.